# How to export/import Data from Microsoft Dynamics crm

Tags: c#, .net, api, dynamics-crm

I am a Java developer and new to ***c# and .Net*** so my question may seem to be  very basic but answer with some example reference will be highly appreciable.

My application wants to communicate with Microsoft Dynamics CRM. Basically
I want to sink the datas between my App and Dynamics crm.

I am looking answers for following.

1) Do Microsoft Dynamics CRM provides some API to export data ?
2) Is there any a kind of listener which my App can keep listening to know that database have been modified ?

Comment: Did you check the documentation? There are a *lot* of ways to export data, calling a REST API etc. What do you mean import/export data? Really import/export from eg CSV, database tables, or call APIs to update customer records?

Comment: @ Panagiotis - here import/export is syncing data. I want my application's db and CRM db to be syn always. Like if some data is entered in CRM it should be updated in my db and vise versa. Since CRM is hosted in a different server i was looking for api which can send me data in json format.

Comment: Thanks Panagiotis for your input :)  Please don't bother about my Application as you are not aware what my Application is and why it should be synced whether it had dozen of columns  or not.  I have asked two question and my solution depends on both the answer. If you can help out with solution please post as Answer.

Comment: Already did. It has both a REST API and export facilities. Check the documentation. It has entire chapters for each of these. You can't expect a reference of the several dozens of APIs in a StackOverflow answer?

Comment: Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt593051.aspx) for starters. Luckily it supports OData so querying should be easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your questions directly:

1. Yes. CRM has a fairly robust API. You can utilize the [REST services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334767.aspx) (recommended for client side browser customization) or [download the full SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547453.aspx) for more complex integrations. You can build data export logic fairly easily with, especially, the full SDK. However, if you are on-premise you might just want to look at going directly to SQL and running 'select' statements if an automated export is all you want.
2. Yes. You can develop plugins which fire on CRUD operations and/or you can develop custom workflows which help facilitate automation. The full SDK has information (and there are tons of resources on the web) which help with this.

Based on the limited information you have posted, I would think you would want to investigate plugin and custom workflow development so you can monitor when records are manipulated and then trigger your integration logic.

Comment: Thanks Jason Faulkner